# ZF2: ServiceLocator in Validator unable to fetch instance

Tags: zend-framework2

I have implemented a custom validator class as follows

```
class UsernameUnique extends AbstractValidator implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

    protected $userManager;

    public function getUserManager()
    {
        if(!$this->userManager)
        {
            $this->userManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('RTUserManager');
        }
        return $this->userManager;
    }

    public isValid()
    {
        $um = $this->getUserManager();
        //rest of code
    }
}
```

I have used this validator in a form.

```
'validators' => array(
    array(
        'name'  => 'RTUser\Form\Validator\EmailUnique'
         )
    )
```

Everything seems fine but when the form validation occurs, I get an exception saying

```
Zend\Validator\ValidatorPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for RTUserManager
```

The stack trace leads to the Validator class.

The 'RTUserManager' could be created from a controller. So there is no problem with the service_manager configuration. But the validator could not create its instance.

How can I work around this?

EDIT :
This is the code in the controller plugin.

```
public function register()
{
    $newuser = $this->getInputValues();

    if($newuser->isValid())
    {
        $userdata = $newuser->getData(FormInterface::VALUES_AS_ARRAY);
        if($this->saveUserToDB($userdata))
        {
            return $message('Registration has been successful. Verify your email address to login.');
        }
    }
    return $this->registrationForm($newuser);
}

protected function getInputValues()
{
    $userdata = $this->getController()->getRequest()->getPost();
    $newuser = new RegistrationForm();
    $newuser->bind($userdata);
    return $newuser;
}
```

Form code.

```
class RegistrationForm extends Form
{
    protected $inputfilter;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        //code to add form elements
        $this->setInputFilter($this->getInputFilter());
    }

    public function getInputFilter() 
    {

       if(!$this->inputfilter)
       {
           $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
           //code to add other validators and filters

           $inputFilter->add(
               'name' => 'email',
               'validators' => array(
                    'name'  => 'RTUser\Form\Validator\EmailUnique',
               )
           );
           $this->inputfilter = $inputFilter;
       }
       return $this->inputfilter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Zend Framework has multiple managers and they all are service locators. Which can be confusing if you only know about the `ServiceManager`

In your validator, `getServiceLocator` does not return the `ServiceManager` but the `ValidatorPluginManager`, which of course has no knowledge of your `service_manager` configuration.
Luckily for you, it extends the `AbstractPluginManager` - which means it contains the actual service manager.

So before getting your service, you need to access the `ServiceManager` first. Instead:

```
$this->userManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('RTUserManager');
```

Try:

```
/** @var ValidatorPluginManager $validatorManager */
$validatorManager = $this->getServiceLocator();
/** @var ServiceManager $serviceManager */
$serviceManager = $validatorManager->getServiceLocator();
$this->userManager = $serviceManager->get('RTUserManager');
```

which is just a clearer notation for:

```
$this->userManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->getServiceLocator()->get('RTUserManager');
```

Lastly, I'd suggest you to write some factory for you validator to inject your dependency `RTUserManager` to not loose track about dependencies. It's not good practice to use any service locator inside of your classes and in Zend 3, service locators might even only be available in factories. But thats optional for now.

**Edit:**

You are right, creating the `InputFilter` directly is your second problem. Because you do so, it can't have any knowledge of the `ServiceManager`. To fix this, you need to:

1. Inject the `InputFilterPluginManager` into a `Zend\InputFilter\Factory`
2. Create the `InputFilter` with this factory

So your `RegistrationForm` should look something like this:

```
class RegistrationForm extends Form
{
    protected $inputfilter;
    /**
     * @var InputFilterPluginManager
     */
    protected $inputFilterManager;

    /**
     * RegistrationForm constructor.
     * @param InputFilterPluginManager $inputFilterManager
     */
    public function __construct(InputFilterPluginManager $inputFilterManager)
    {
        $this->setInputFilterManager($inputFilterManager);
        parent::__construct("registration");
        //code to add form elements
        $this->setInputFilter($this->getInputFilter());
    }

    public function getInputFilter()
    {
        if(!$this->inputfilter)
        {
            $factory = new Factory($this->getInputFilterManager());
            $inputFilter = $factory->createInputFilter(array(
                // other input specifications
                "email" => array(
                    'name'       => 'email',
                    'validators' => array(
                        array(
                            'name' => 'Application\Form\Validator\EmailUnique',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ));
            $this->inputfilter = $inputFilter;
        }
        return $this->inputfilter;
    }

    /**
     * @return InputFilterPluginManager
     */
    public function getInputFilterManager()
    {
        return $this->inputFilterManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param InputFilterPluginManager $inputFilterManager
     */
    public function setInputFilterManager($inputFilterManager)
    {
        $this->inputFilterManager = $inputFilterManager;
    }

}
```

And you either need to pass the `InputFilterPluginManager` directly when instantiating the `RegistrationForm` or you build a factory for it. For simplicity, I'll just extend your current plugin code although I'd prefer a factory:

```
protected function getInputValues()
{
    /** @var InputFilterPluginManager $inputManager */
    $inputManager = $this->getController()->getServiceLocator()->get("InputFilterManager");
    $userdata = $this->getController()->getRequest()->getPost();
    $newuser = new RegistrationForm($inputManager);
    $newuser->bind($userdata);
    return $newuser;
}
```

And that's it. The factory is able to access all managers through the `InputFilterPluginManager` and can therefore create validators with proper dependency injections.

Comment: I have already tried this. But `$this->getServiceLocator()->getServiceLocator();` returns a null. Could it be a reason that I am creating the instance of form using the `new` keyword.

Comment: Creating the instance of your validator? If so, probably yes, please add the code where you create the validator.

Comment: No. Validator is instanciated by zend implicitly. Only the form is created with `new` keyword. I have edited the question to add the code.

Comment: I also have tried to create input filter from a service. But it gives the same result.

Comment: That worked with a small change. In the form, parent constructor had to be called before calling `$this->setInputFilter()`. Otherwise, `Call to a member function insert() on null` exception was raised. It might be useful for others if you change that in your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I did. Just out of interest: Which Zend version do you use? Seems to depend, 2.5 works

Comment: I am actually using 2.5.
2.5.2 to be precise.

Comment: That's strange, I was wondering why you didn't add the parent constructor anyways, because this threw me a fatal error. Anyhow, I don't think this is part of the question anymore.

Comment: I did add it. But did not mention it in the question's code.